# Memory Protection without MMU

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I would like to know how memory can be protected without MMU support. I have tried to google it, but have not seen any worthwile papers or research on it. And those which deal with it only deals it for bugs, such as uninitialized pointers and not memory corruption due to a soft error, that is, due to a hardware transient fault corrupting an instruction that writes to a memory location.

The reason I want to know this is because I am working on a proprietary manycore platform without any Memory Protection. Now my question is, can software be used to protect memory, especially for wild writes due to soft erros (as opposed to mistakes by a programmer). Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Wound't valgrind do what you need?

Comment: I don't need it for debugging, but avoiding wild writes to corrupt memory at runtime. Basically I want a secure and reliable system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking for Runtime memory protection the sane only option is hardware support.  Hardware is the only way to intervene in a bad memory access before it can cause damage.  Any software solution would be vulnerable to the very memory errors it is trying to protect against.

With software you could possibly implement a verification/detection scheme.  You could periodically check portions of memory that the currently running program should not have access and see if they have changed (probably by CRCing these areas).  But of course if the rogue program damages the area where the checksums are held, or where the checking program's code is held, then all bets are off.

Even this software checking solution would be more of a debugging utility than a permanent runtime protection.  It is likely that a device with no MMU is a small embedded device which won't have the spare cycles to be constantly checking the device's memory.

Usually devices without MMUs are designed to run a single program with no kernel or anything else, and thus there is nothing to protect.  If you need to run multiple programs and feel you need protection, you probably need a more advanced piece of hardware that supports the kind of features you're looking for.

Comment: If memory protection can be implemented in hardware, it presumably could be implemented in software.

Comment: @David: Sure, by emulating hardware.  At that point it would just be a virtual machine.  Then the speed of the actual hardware comes in to play.  Presumably this guy isn't interested in implementing his own VM, because that would be kind of crazy.

Comment: I agree with all of that. I just took issue with you saying that hardware was the only way. Perhaps you could say hardware is the only realistic or sane way. That's all!

Answer (score 2):

If you want software implemented memory protection, then you will need support from your compiler and its associated libraries. I expect that there is one compiler only on this platform and so you should contact the vendor. I wouldn't hold out much hope for a positive response. Even if they had such tools, I would expect the performance of software memory protection to be unacceptable.

Comment: What kind of support. I mean, what would be the mechanism?

Comment: The compiler would normally write a simple read or write instruction every time memory was accessed. But you would need every such instruction to be replaced by a call to a library function that performed the runtime protection you are looking for.

Comment: ... and if you're going to go to that extreme, you might as well just port your program over to e.g. Python or Lua and be done with it.  You'd get better performance and likely similar stability.

Answer (score 1):

MMU less systems are present in several embedded solutions.

The memory is managed by the kernel code. The entire memory (heap) is divided into heap lists of various sizes (heap lists can be of sizes 4 bytes, 8 bytes, 16 bytes ..... upto 1024 bytes)and there's a header attached to each heap block that tells whether the particular heap block is taken or not. So, that when u need to assign a new heap block, you can browse through the heap lists and see which heap blocks are free and can assign them to the requesting application. And the same is the case when you free a particular sized heap block, the headers of that block are updated to reflect that it has been freed.

Now, this implementation has to take care of the scenario when the application requested a particular size of heap block and that size of heap list is full. In that case you break up a block from the next size of heap list or join together smaller sized heap blocks and add to the requested sized heap list.

The implementation is much simpler than it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what application platform will run. There is technology called Type-Safe Language (ATS, for instance) which can protect from software errors. And such languages may have good performance (again ATS, for instance).